# Index optimisation: avg_leaf_density field

Tags: postgresql

I used the pgstatindex module to make a sanity check of index. What does the `avg_leaf_density` field mean that is returned?

```
SELECT i.indexrelid::regclass AS index,
       s.index_size,
       s.avg_leaf_density
FROM pg_index AS i
CROSS JOIN LATERAL pgstatindex(i.indexrelid) AS s
WHERE indrelid = 'myschema.mytable'::regclass;
```

avg_leaf_density = 77.61

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is calculated like this:

```c
100.0 - (double) indexStat.free_space / (double) indexStat.max_avail * 100.0
```

Here, `free_space` is the unused space in the index and `max_avail` is the free space if all index pages were empty.

So `avg_leaf_density` is the percentage of the available space in the index that is occupied with data.

Note that with the default `fillfactor` of 90, you should not expect values above that with a newly built index. Values down to about 30 are normal and nothing to worry about.

Comment: Exactly. Mind the `fillfactor`.